# How start soapui in RDP when another use is connected?

Tags: java, windows, soapui, rdp

I use soapui 5.0.0 communiy edition. When I use this program via rdp and I am a single user (no other user connected) it works well. But when somebody else login to the system (not via RDP in my case), soapui holds and do not respond. Restart, reinstall do not helps until another user logs out.

Is there a way to start soapui when another use connected to system?

I use windows Server 2008 R2 x64, java 7 update 60.

**UPDATED**

Also as I see with JProfiler method `sun.java2d.d3d.D3DRenderQueue.flushBuffer` loads system all time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is jre issue. I saw a bug report for oracle jre, but forget to save a link about this. I fixed my issue with downloaded open jre **1.6** and use it. According to `soapui.bat` you can change jre simply delete `Soapui/jre` and paste `jre` from [these](https://github.com/alexkasko/openjdk-unofficial-builds#openjdk-unofficial-installers-for-windows-linux-and-mac-os-x) archives.

**Note**

At current moment soapui is x32 applciation, so you have to copy x32 (i586) version into soapui jre folder. I tried to use x64 jre, but get error that jre is damaged.